# How to show the same Image at the same location on each page in the RDLC 2010 report

Tags: asp.net, image, report, reportviewer, rdlc

I am composing an RDLC report in Visual Studio 2010.

I need to display the same image at the same location on each generated page.

The image is a background image and needs to be overlapped by one table on the same page.
If the table needs to extend to many pages the image must be repeated on each page at the same
location relative to the page.

I tried to put the image to be a part of the page background but then the image is stretched or repeated as tiles. The only available options at my disposal for the background image to repeat are Default, Repeat, RepeatX, RepeatY or Clip.

What can be the best possible solution to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the only solution acceptable for me was to design the image on the A4 paper and put the entire image as a background bitmap of the page template with the Repeat property set to Clip. I hope there will be better solutions then this but for now this the only one I have found.